# counting the unique items in the excelsheet

Tags: excel, count, unique

I need to count the number of unique items (here I have the names of organizations) in the excel-sheet...I used the following script but I cannot introduce multiple inputs to count all of them at once.

```
 =SUMPRODUCT((A27:A128<>"")/COUNTIF(A27:A128,A27:A128&""))
```

I want to introduce, for instance, A27:A128, A145:A156 lists of cells to be checked and counted.

Does anyone know how I can count them? Is there another function to be called?

Comment: Is introducing a helping column an option or must it be one single formula?

Comment: I should include it at the end of the report (Excelsheet)..so It should be one single equation showing the number of involved organizations.

Comment: In this case please add further detail about the sheet. Are all areas you want to test in the same column or are they spread out over the whole sheet? If it is the same column, what other data is there inbetween the areas, is it only empty cells or is there some other text inbetween? If there is some other text, could one of the excluded texts ever be equal to one of the included ones?

Comment: They are all in the same column but there exist some cells which could be either empty or filled, or even merged with some adjacent cells.

Comment: Merging is no problem. Given that no value of an included cell might appear in a not included cell, i'll provide an answer below. If this is not the case, we're going for a much more complex solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Very simple........use a "helper" column, say column **D**  In D1 enter:

**=A27**  and copy down thru D102.

In D103 enter:

**=A145**  and copy down thru D114

Finally use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D1:D114<>"")/COUNTIF(D1:D114,D1:D114&""))
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula you need looks like the following

```
=SUM( IF( MATCH(A27:A128,A:A,0)=ROW(A27:A128) , 1 , 0 ) , 
      IF( MATCH(A145:A156,A:A,0)=ROW(A145:A156) , 1 , 0 ))
```

and works like this:

For every area you want to check you need the following construct:

```
IF( MATCH(A27:A128,A:A,0)=ROW(A27:A128) , 1 , 0 )
```

This tries to match every cell from A27 to A128 to the whole column A and checks, if the row where the value was found is equal to the current row. If this is the case, we found the first occurence, if it is a repeated occurence, the row will be smaller (because MATCH always returns the first row where the value was found). Now if we found a first occurence, IF returns 1, otherwise 0.

SUM just sums up every if (that means, if you have a third area and so on, just keep adding more IF-constructs and you're done), resulting in summing up a 1 for every first occurence of a value and a 0 for every follow-up - and you get your amount of unique values.

**Attention:** The whole formula is a matrix formula. After you put it in the cell, you must not end the editing with pressing ENTER but with **STRG+SHIFT+ENTER** simultaneously. This way excel surrounds the formula with {}-brackets that you cannot enter manually. It changes the way excel evaluates the formula and you might get an error if you try it as normal formula.

Also, as the values get checked against the whole column A the formula might or might not fail, if a certain value appears inside and outside of a checked area, depending on the ordering of the values.